# Cant access object properties retrieved via API with error message TypeError: Cannot read property '' of undefined - Nextjs/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, api, next.js

I have a problem that appears to be unique to NextJs.

I am hitting an API through a useHook and retrieving the results. What I get back is an array of objects. Everything works fine and I can console.log the entire result (Array of objects).

```
  const mymoviegenreobjects = useFetchNavBarCatagories();
```

*[{
"id": "1",
"name": "Adventure",
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "Horror"
},
{
"id": 3,
"name": "Action"
}]*

Then I filter the array of objects so that I can find which object has a name key that is = to 'Adventure'. That also works fine and I am able to extract the object which has the name key = to "Adventure" and now what I get back is an array with one object inside (the correct one).

```
 const avengers = mymoviegenreobjects.filter(
    (character) => character.name === "Adventure"
  );
```

*[{
"id": "1",
"name": "Adventure",
}]*

Then to access the correct element of the array I use the [0] method which allows me to console.log just the first object. However when I want to console.log the first object.id which I do like thi

```
   console.log("The ID for Avengers is", avengers[0].id)
```

I get this error.

**Server Error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined**

I am not sure why this is happening as this is the correct way to access the element in an array of objects, then a particular element within the selected object.

I have read some very vague explanation [link below] but I was unable to make out why this was actually happening and how to solve it. Furthermore, I've also read elsewhere that process.window is a deprecated function and should not be used.

So my question is how would I access the ID property of my object so that I would be able to console.log it and/or store it in a different variable.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

[Next.js TypeError: Cannot read property '' of undefined when trying to console log api results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70131767/next-js-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-when-trying-to-console-l)

I have added a code sandbox to help you understand my error and what I am trying to do. Please disregard all my commented out stuff as I am just playing around and trying to do different stuff. Link is below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-neumann-2x6iff

What I am trying to do is access the individual properties of the last console.log (This is avangers two)

The code for the log can be found in the usefetchMovieGenreResults hook.

I also tried to implement painting the object on the screen on the MovieGenreResults component just to see what happens but it does not work (as expected). I used the hook above to feed it. Ideally I would use the . notion to access the specific element I want to paint however it gives me an error.

Comment: Can you paste the full code related to your question?

Comment: Added a code sandbox of my entire code. @HarshanaSerasinghe

Comment: It's because the variable `mymoviegenreobjects` is `undefined` when the page gets pre-rendered on server, as the data fetching happens inside `useEffect` on the client-side only. You have to check if `mymoviegenreobjects` in `undefined` before trying to access/manipulate its contents.

Comment: @juliomalves  Then why is it that I can I map my mymoviegenreobject using line 22 and 26 in my useFetchMoviegenreresults hook?  Or why does console.log("This is avangers two", avengerstwo) which is line 72 return the object I want on the browser console? I am looking to take that returned object and access its properties so I can store them in different variables. Furthermore, how would I implement your suggestion? Would I put the check for mymoviegenreobjects in an 'If' statement? Something like If mymoviegenreobjects !== null?. Feel free to reply with the bit of code you think needs editing.

Comment: You can see the expected output for `avengerstwo` in the browser because, as I mentioned, the data is fetched only on the client. If you check your logs on the server (terminal where you started the dev server) you'll see that value is `undefined`. The issue happens when pre-rendedering the page on the server, not in the browser. Having a condition like `if (mymoviegenreobjects.genres.length > 0) { ... }` should work fine. Also, small correction from my previous comment, `mymoviegenreobjects` is not undefined on the server, it's `mymoviegenreobjects.genres` that's an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

can you make a codesandbox? It seems you're using next.js, calling the api on the server but logging the result in the jsx, you need to receive props to the component to achieve that [next.js server side data fetching](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props)

Comment: Added a code Sandbox @Aman

Comment: I've looked into the code, it's hard to understand but i guess the problem is this, const results = useFetchMovieGenreResults(Genre); Here results is undefined you might want to use optional chaining.   <Moviegenreresults genre={Genre} id={results?.id} />
Further, you need to set the array coming from server into some state, otherwise the page wont re-render. In your custom hook, fetch the data and setState(data), and return this state not data. then access data[query.id]